# Managing Historical Data Dependencies

Tags: mysql, database-design

3 Tables: `Device`, `SoftwareRevision`, `Message`. All data entered is handed by PHP scripts on an Apache server.

A device can have one software revision. A software revision can have many devices. A device can have many messages. A message can have one device.

[image]

Something like above.

The issue is, the `SoftwareRevision` changes how the message is used in the front end application. This means that when the software is updated on the device, we need older messages to retain the information that they were received from a different software revision.

The TL;DR here is that the fully normalized way I see of doing this becomes a real pain. I've got about 5 of these situations in my current project and 3 of them are nested inside of each other.

---

---

I see three ways of doing this:

[image: Normalized DB]

The first is the above fully normalized way. In order to find out how to use the message on the front end application, one must find the latest entry into `Device_SoftwareRevision_Records` that is before the `datetime` of the given message. This gets really fiddly when you have a more complex database and application. Just to get the current `SoftwareRevision_ID` for a device you have to use a MAX GROUP BY type statement (I've ended up having to use views to simplify).

---

[image: Slightly Denormalized DB]

The second is to directly link the Message to the `SoftwareVersion`. This means you don't have to go through the whole `MAX` `GROUP BY` `WHERE` blah blah. The `SoftwareVersion_ID` is retrieved by a PHP script and then the message is entered. Of course, this is denormalized so now there is potential for duplicate data.

---

[image: Fully Denormalized DB]

Aaaand heres our fully denormalized version. The `Software_Revision_Records` table is purely for bookkeeping purposes. Easy to use for the front-end application but a pain to update at the back-end. The back-end updating can actually be streamlined with triggers for entering into the `Software_Revision_Records` table so the only thing that can really go wrong is the message gets the wrong software revision when it is entered.

---

Is there a better way of doing this that I have missed? Is it such a sin to denormalize the database in this situation? Will my decision here cause the business to erupt into flames (probably not)?

Comment: Would it not be appropriate to add the date column to the softwarerevision table?

Comment: @Strawberry 
Different devices may be updated at different times. Possibly never even. (I think that was what you were asking)

Comment: It's not a sin to denormalize.  If you understand the risks and doing so enables you to prove a more effective/efficient solution, go for it.  Perhaps look into check constraints / triggers to ensure integrity.

Comment: I would stick with the normalised model.

Answer (score 1):

If the messages are tied to the software revision for that particular device, then it might make more sense to reflect that relationship in the data model. i.e. have a foreign key from Messages to Device_SoftwareRevision_Records rather than from Messages to Device. You still have the relationship from Messages to Device indirectly, it's normalised, and there's no messing around with dates trying to figure out which messages were created while a given software revision was in place.

In cases where you do need dates, it might also be worth considering having both a start and stop date, and filling in any null dates with something like 9999-12-31 (to indicate that a record has not yet been ended). You can easily find the latest record without needing to do a `max`. It will also make it a lot easier to query the table if you do need to compare it to other dates - you can just do a between on a single record. In this example, you'd just look for this:

`where Message.TimeStamp between Device_SoftwareRevision_Records.StartDate and Device_SoftwareRevision_Records.EndDate`

That said, I would still - if at all possible - change the model to relate Messages to the correct table rather than rely on dates. Being able to do simple joins will be quicker, more convenient, more obvious if anyone new needs to learn the structure, and is likely to perform better.